# Regex Replace with only once

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Apologies if this question has been asked before, I simply don't know how to phrase it in such a way as to garner a useable result.

I am using the .net framework to "find and replace" strings with the string, but surrounded in HTML tags using the backreference technique.

```
pText = Regex.Replace("aa", "aa likes bb", "<span class='cat'>$0</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

This was working fine, until such a time that the keywords I was looking to replace had already been replaced as part of a bigger word.

For example - `using the keywords aa, bb, aabb`:

`aa likes bb` becomes [image: <span class="aa">aa</span> likes <span class="bb">bb</span>.]

However:

`aa likes aabb` becomes [image: <span class="aa">aa</strong> likes <span class="aabb"><span class="aa">aa</span>bb</span>]

I somehow need it to establish that a replace has already occured, and render as

[image]

Comment: Would the following regex works for you? `\b(aa|bb|aabb)\b`

Comment: Unfortunately the aa, bb, aabb are all user definable.

Comment: Can you make the hypothesis that the aa, bb, aabb are complete words, or could partial words also be entered, other characters?

Comment: I'm afraid not, they can be a series of words.

Comment: Then I afraid to say there might be no direct solution to your problem... and you will need to keep a data set of past replacements and check that new replacements are not already part of the previous elements before applying them...

Comment: I feared this was the case, figured I’d ask as I’m not exactly regex familiar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161169/discussion-between-allan-and-matt-skeldon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this can count as an answer but as a matter of completeness and in the event someone else ends up here with the same scenario I was definatly overthinking this.

Rather than tweaking any of the Regex / Code I simply applied the following LESS / CSS Rules.

```
.fa-metal(@Color){
    background-color: @Color;
    padding: 1px 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid darken(@Color, 10%);

    /*Ensure that a code inside a code will not be rendered*/
    .fa-bronze, .fa-silver, .fa-gold {
        background-color: transparent;
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        border: none;
    }
}
```

This way when a class was double replaced only the outermost span is rendered. (The HTML source is a littered with unecessary spans, but I can live with that)

Answer (score 0):

Try using word boundaries around the keywords that you are searching for. For example, the regex `\baa\b` will only match the first occurrence of aa in the text `aa likes aabb`, instead of matching both occurrences of it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the assistance. Unfortunately this won’t work as they can be phrases not just words.